# How to edit the existing file on the linux server using jsch

Tags: java, linux, sftp, jsch

I have a file on the linux server that contains the system date of the application.
The file name is "abc.property." and the file contains the systemdate parameter which application reads.
e.g the content of the file is below:-

```
1.SYSTEMDATE= 20162201 160 
2.ABC
3.XYZ
4.CCC
```

I want to write a java program that will connect to the server using JSCH and allow me to change the system date through the application.

I already have a code to connect to the server and read the content.

```
ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
session.sendKeepAliveMsg();
sftpChannel.connect();     
session.sendKeepAliveMsg();
sftpChannel.cd("path");
InputStream out= null;
out= sftpChannel.get(remoteFile);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(out));
String line;
session.sendKeepAliveMsg();
System.out.println(workingDir);
```

Can any one help me on this?? i am new to jsch programming.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific in what you want?

Comment: i want to write a program that will update the system date from the "abc.property" file. when i want to change the system date every time i login to linux server and do it using the "vi abc.property" command, so is there any way i can do the same using jsch?

Comment: Please let me know if you need any other information on the same.I have code to read the file content. i am just trying to write a program that will allow me to do the same without logging in to the linux server every time.

Comment: @hotzst I am basically a tester, trying to write a program that will help me in day to day activities.so one of my task during testing is to change the system date and test the application,so i want to automate this process of changing the system date using a java program.

Comment: Why invoke `vi` from a program when you can use simple things like `sed`?

Comment: @SergeyTachenov Thank you for your input,i will try with sed and let you know the result.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov I will now execute this command through jsch "sed -i 's/.*SYS.*/#SYSTEMDTE 20150326 1090/g' test.txt" to change the date in the file.This will solve my problem.Thanks a lot for your input.